# How to switch to Md-dialog in selenium?

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

I am having an issue in regards to a md-dialog pop-up in an angularJS app that I am unable to click in selenium. When i click a button the dialog box appears and becomes the active element on the screen, darkening the background. I have tried switchTo with active element, frame, alert and none of these seem to work. My most recent attempt was trying to swap windows using the below code:

```
winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> numOfWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.print(numOfWindows.size());
for(String winhandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
{
    driver.switchTo().window(winhandle);
    report.updateTestLog("Switched to window", "", Status.PASS);
}
```

the S.o.p for the size is always outputted as 1. There is a wait in after the initial button is clicked before the popup appears to assure it has the proper time to appear. Not sure what else there is to do, I have been scouring the internet for an answer and I haven't come across anything that will let me click the elements in that popup

Edit: This is the html for the md-dialog

```
<md-dialog class="quote _md md-transition-in" aria-label="Summary" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="dialogContent_78" aria-describedby="dialogContent_78" style="">
```

Edit 2: Forgot to say, I am trying to click a button inside the md-dialog popup

Edit 3: After reviewing the code a bit more I noticed that the md-dialog popup has a container div that is taking up the entire screen and that it is also calling in html from another file. The container div html:`<div class="md-dialog-container ng-scope" tabindex="-1" style="top: 972px; height: 769px;">`

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `popup`? What is the _usecase_? What are you trying to validate?

Comment: `md-dialog` exists in the same DOM, so you don't need to switch to anything. You should be able to access it normally using id after it's displayed.

Comment: @OmarEinea, It doesn't have an ID and i right clicked and used an xpath generated by google to find it's exact location, even included a wait time of 50 seconds and still nothing. I think it might be because it is different html being called into an md dialog, the md dialog has a container div that takes up the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has same issue the pop-up was registering as hidden even though it had appeared on screen, so any attempt to click a button was futile as the button was seen as hidden. The workaround was to find the button using the findElement() method, assign it to a variable and then use a javascriptExectutor to click it even though it was hidden. This is not ideal if you are trying to reproduce user input but it is a workaround. Code is below.

```
    WebElement hiddenButton = driver.findElement(uniqueIdentifier);

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", hiddenButton);
    report.updateTestLog(flowName, uniqueIdentifier + " Hidden Button Pressed", Status.DONE);
```

Hope this helps anyone who finds it.